# generate documentation for sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a multiplayer game with the framework Phaser. For the server side, I use node.js.

To communicate between the game and the server, I use socket.io.

I am looking for a tool like swagger-ui or apidoc to generate the documentation of sockets in the server.

An example of socket :

"foo" which need to receive one string in parameter and who will send back another string like "bar". "foo" can also broadcast data to every players on the event named "update".

**Do you know a tool which is capable to generate a socket documentation?**